# Drawing plankton with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can anyone suggest a method for drawing random plankton communities with TikZ? Similar to

[image]

I know it is possible to save the image and then load it into LaTeX but I was hoping there was a way of drawing these individually.

Comment: Loading the picture seems like the way to go here. (It looks too difficult to create a drawing like this, but then I don't know TikZ.)

Comment: Also, you should try and come up with something yourself; this is not a "please do it for me" side. `:)`

Comment: Do you mean draw random critters in random positions/orientations?

Comment: A mere comment: if you have vectors (or rasters, but...gross) of the plankton, you can use TikZ to place them in random locations.

Comment: –1: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Or, you could use pgf 3.0.0 and the `pic` syntax.

```
\documentclass[border=0.12cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  plankton 1/.pic={
    \fill [green!20!brown]        
     \foreach \i in {1,2,3}{
       [rotate=\i*120]  (0,1.125) ellipse [x radius=.5, y radius=1]
     };
    \clip [preaction={fill=blue!60}]
      circle [radius=1.125];
    \foreach \i in {1,...,50}
      \fill [blue!70] (rnd*360:rnd*1.125)
        circle [radius=0.125]; 
  },
  plankton 2/.pic={
    \draw [thick, line cap=round, black!80]
      (-0.125,2) to [bend right] ++(120:1.125)
      ( 0.125,2) to [bend left]  ++(60:1.125)
      (-0.125,0) to [bend left]  ++(240:1)
      ( 0.125,0) to [bend right] ++(300:1);
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\l=2+\i/4;}] in {1,...,4}
      \draw [black!80]
        (-0.125,\i/8) to [bend right, out=270, in=270, looseness=\l] (0,1+\i/4)
        (-0.125,\i/8) to [bend right, out=90,  in=90,  looseness=\l] (0,1+\i/4);
     \foreach \i [evaluate={\j=mod(\i,2)*10+10;}] in {1,...,8}
      \fill [green!\j!brown] (0,\i/4) 
        ellipse [x radius=(4+\i)/16, y radius=0.25]; 
  },
  plankton 3/.pic={
    \fill [green!20!brown]
      ellipse [x radius=0.25, y radius=1];
    \fill [green!10!brown]
      ellipse [x radius=0.25, y radius=0.5];
    \draw [thick, black, line cap=round]
     (-0.5,-2) to [bend right, looseness=.5] (-0.5,2)
     ( 0.5,-2) to [bend left,  looseness=.5] ( 0.5,2);
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5pt,y=5pt]
\fill [blue!20]
  (0,0) -- (55,0) -- (55,10)
    decorate [decoration={snake, segment length=1cm, amplitude=.125cm}] 
   { -- (0,10) } -- cycle;
\foreach \i [evaluate={\p=int(random(1,3))}] in {1,...,10}
\path (\i*5, rnd*5+2.5) pic [rotate=rnd*360] {plankton \p};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's impressively little code!

Answer (score 31):

Well, here's *a* plankton. Anyone for a Krabby Patty?

```
\documentclass[border=0.12cm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5pt,y=5pt]
\definecolor{feelers}{rgb}{0.12, 0.41, 0.15}
\definecolor{plankton}{rgb}{0.57, 0.76, 0.66}

\path [line width=8, fill=feelers, draw=black]  (32.58,159.92)
  .. controls (32.58,159.92) and (20.61,184.16) .. (16.15,201.98)
  .. controls (11.69,219.81) and ( 7.24,246.54) .. ( 6.40,257.41)
  .. controls ( 5.57,268.27) and ( 6.68,303.08) .. ( 8.63,312.27)
  .. controls (10.58,321.46) and (13.36,327.31) .. (13.36,327.31)
  .. controls (13.36,327.31) and ( 8.63,304.47) .. ( 8.07,296.68)
  .. controls ( 7.51,288.88) and ( 6.40,261.86) .. ( 8.35,250.72)
  .. controls (10.30,239.58) and (18.10,200.59) .. (28.68,182.21)
  .. controls (39.27,163.82) and (40.10,164.38) .. (40.10,164.38)
  -- cycle;

\path [fill=black]  ( 6.68,206.71)
  -- (22.28,212.01) -- (23.67,208.94)
  -- ( 8.35,202.82) -- cycle
  %
  ( 3.34,229.83)
  -- (16.15,234.01) -- (17.54,229.83)
  -- ( 4.45,226.21) -- cycle
  %
  ( 0.83,256.85)
  -- (11.97,257.68) -- (12.53,255.18)
  -- (0,254.90) -- cycle
  %
  ( 0.27,287.21)
  -- (11.69,286.65) -- (11.69,283.59)
  -- ( 0.83,283.59) -- cycle;

\path [draw=black, line width=8, fill=plankton]  (24.94,83.99)
  .. controls (24.94,83.99) and (22.96,126.14) .. (24.83,139.12)
  .. controls (26.46,150.34) and (31.37,173.15) .. (52.25,172.35)
  .. controls (68.73,171.71) and (80.36,160.70) .. (79.56,134.59)
  .. controls (78.65,104.85) and (80.77,91.62) .. (80.77,91.62)
  .. controls (80.77,91.62) and (97.23,86.00) .. (100.85,78.77)
  .. controls (104.46,71.54) and (100.04,70.34) .. (95.63,66.32)
  .. controls (91.21,62.31) and (88.00,61.90) .. (88.00,61.90)
  .. controls (88.00,61.90) and (90.40,61.90) .. (92.41,58.29)
  .. controls (94.42,54.67) and (88.40,53.47) .. (86.39,55.48)
  .. controls (84.38,57.49) and (82.58,57.61) .. (82.37,59.49)
  .. controls (81.99,62.96) and (83.98,64.31) .. (88.00,68.33)
  .. controls (93.48,73.81) and (94.82,75.96) .. (89.60,78.77)
  .. controls (84.38,81.58) and (80.36,83.99) .. (80.36,83.99)
  .. controls (80.36,83.99) and (85.18,53.07) .. (87.19,43.43)
  .. controls (89.20,33.79) and (86.39,28.97) .. (86.39,28.97)
  .. controls (86.39,28.97) and (89.60,25.76) .. (94.42,20.54)
  .. controls (99.24,15.32) and (100.44, 7.69) .. (96.43,10.50)
  .. controls (92.41,13.31) and (80.36,24.55) .. (80.36,24.55)
  -- (82.77,22.55)
  .. controls (82.77,22.55) and (71.13,18.53) .. (65.51,18.93)
  .. controls (59.88,19.33) and (56.27,20.94) .. (56.27,20.94)
  -- (58.14,20.08)
  .. controls (58.14,20.08) and (58.28,17.73) .. (57.87,12.10)
  .. controls (57.47, 6.48) and (58.40,-4.30) .. (54.66, 4.07)
  .. controls (51.29,11.63) and (50.24,24.96) .. (50.24,24.96)
  .. controls (50.24,24.96) and (34.98,46.64) .. (33.78,55.88)
  .. controls (32.57,65.12) and (27.75,75.16) .. (27.75,75.16)
  -- (16.11,68.73)
  -- (18.52,70.34)
  .. controls (18.52,70.34) and (24.14,66.32) .. (28.16,64.31)
  .. controls (32.17,62.31) and (35.38,58.69) .. (32.98,55.88)
  .. controls (30.57,53.07) and (20.93,51.86) .. (24.14,55.88)
  .. controls (27.35,59.90) and (27.35,60.70) .. (27.35,60.70)
  .. controls (27.35,60.70) and (14.10,60.30) .. (10.89,65.92)
  .. controls ( 7.67,71.54) and (11.29,73.15) .. (16.91,76.76)
  .. controls (22.53,80.38) and (24.94,83.99) .. (24.94,83.99)
  -- cycle;

\path [line width=4,draw=black,fill=white]  (39.33,69.44)
  .. controls (39.33,69.44) and (52.59,68.07) .. (59.75,71.73)
  .. controls (66.92,75.39) and (73.47,83.31) .. (73.47,83.31)
  .. controls (73.47,83.31) and (73.93,66.24) .. (71.49,62.43)
  .. controls (69.05,58.62) and (64.94,54.04) .. (57.77,52.98)
  .. controls (50.61,51.91) and (44.51,55.11) .. (44.51,55.11)
  -- (47.86,53.44)
  .. controls (47.86,53.44) and (48.78,59.69) .. (47.86,63.19)
  .. controls (46.95,66.70) and (46.34,69.14) .. (46.34,69.14)
  -- cycle;

\path [draw=black, line width=4]  (68.90,85.29)
  .. controls (68.90,85.29) and (71.65,85.45) .. (73.47,83.77)
  .. controls (75.30,82.09) and (76.07,80.57) .. (76.07,80.57)
  %
  (48.63,61.21)
  .. controls (48.63,61.21) and (56.25,61.06) .. (61.74,63.19)
  .. controls (67.22,65.33) and (73.02,68.53) .. (73.02,68.53)
  %
  (52.90,69.59)
  .. controls (52.90,69.59) and (53.96,64.26) .. (54.57,60.75)
  .. controls (55.18,57.25) and (55.49,52.52) .. (55.49,52.52)
  %
  (59.60,71.42)
  .. controls (59.60,71.42) and (61.28,66.24) .. (61.89,62.58)
  .. controls (62.50,58.92) and (63.57,54.81) .. (63.57,54.81)
  %
  (66.31,75.84)
  -- (69.51,59.99);

\path [draw=black, line width=4,fill=yellow!20]  (52.29,122.03)
  -- (34.45,113.04)
  .. controls (34.45,113.04) and (36.58,97.79) .. (39.94,92.00)
  .. controls (43.29,86.21) and (46.65,81.94) .. (51.68,81.94)
  .. controls (56.71,81.94) and (61.89,85.75) .. (64.18,93.83)
  .. controls (66.46,101.91) and (65.85,119.59) .. (65.85,119.59)
  -- cycle;

\path [current path/.try, fill=orange!35!red]  (60.67,106.64)
  .. controls (60.67,99.90) and (56.10,94.44) .. (50.46,94.44)
  .. controls (44.82,94.44) and (40.24,99.90) .. (40.24,106.64)
  .. controls (40.24,113.37) and (44.82,118.83) .. (50.46,118.83)
  .. controls (56.10,118.83) and (60.67,113.37) .. (60.67,106.64)
  -- cycle;

\path [fill=white]  (54.11,108.16)
  .. controls (54.11,104.62) and (51.90,101.76) .. (49.16,101.76)
  .. controls (46.42,101.76) and (44.21,104.62) .. (44.21,108.16)
  .. controls (44.21,111.70) and (46.42,114.56) .. (49.16,114.56)
  .. controls (51.90,114.56) and (54.11,111.70) .. (54.11,108.16)
  -- cycle;

\path [draw=black, line width=4, fill=plankton]  (62.96,121.27)
  .. controls (62.96,121.27) and (66.00,123.25) .. (67.53,120.81)
  .. controls (69.05,118.37) and (59.45,113.04) .. (51.22,112.43)
  .. controls (42.99,111.82) and (32.16,112.12) .. (31.71,114.56)
  .. controls (31.25,117.00) and (34.45,118.07) .. (34.45,118.07)
  .. controls (34.45,118.07) and (34.45,129.20) .. (39.02,135.75)
  .. controls (43.60,142.31) and (46.19,143.68) .. (50.91,142.31)
  .. controls (55.64,140.94) and (59.60,136.67) .. (62.80,130.11)
  .. controls (66.00,123.56) and (65.85,121.88) .. (65.85,121.88)
  -- cycle;


\path [draw=black, line width=4]  (38.72,117.15)
  .. controls (38.72,117.15) and (40.70,116.54) .. (43.60,116.70)
  .. controls (46.49,116.85) and (47.71,116.85) .. (47.71,116.85);

\path [fill=black]  (31.27,152.90)
  .. controls (31.27,152.90) and (33.93,159.81) .. (46.87,159.91)
  .. controls (59.81,160.01) and (64.74,151.32) .. (64.74,151.32)
  .. controls (64.74,151.32) and (64.05,149.25) .. (65.34,148.16)
  .. controls (66.62,147.08) and (66.52,145.10) .. (66.52,145.10)
  -- (63.95,146.19)
  .. controls (63.95,146.19) and (63.36,145.20) .. (64.65,144.01)
  .. controls (65.93,142.83) and (65.53,141.74) .. (65.53,141.74)
  .. controls (65.53,141.74) and (59.71,149.45) .. (51.91,148.95)
  .. controls (44.11,148.46) and (36.60,144.51) .. (36.60,144.51)
  .. controls (36.60,144.51) and (36.90,146.29) .. (38.18,147.57)
  .. controls (39.46,148.85) and (39.66,149.15) .. (39.66,149.15)
  -- (33.93,148.66)
  .. controls (33.93,148.66) and (34.72,150.93) .. (36.01,151.72)
  .. controls (37.29,152.51) and (37.69,153.00) .. (37.69,153.00)
  -- cycle;

\path [fill=black]  (41.04,161.79)
  .. controls (41.04,161.79) and (42.23,167.52) .. (50.33,167.62)
  .. controls (58.42,167.71) and (61.29,160.70) .. (61.29,160.70)
  .. controls (61.29,160.70) and (58.82,164.95) .. (50.23,164.95)
  .. controls (41.64,164.95) and (41.04,161.79) .. (41.04,161.79)
  -- cycle;

\path [line width=8,draw=black,fill=feelers]  (62.97,168.01)
  .. controls (62.97,168.01) and (65.04,207.51) .. (69.19,220.74)
  .. controls (73.34,233.98) and (76.89,252.54) .. (84.59,268.74)
  .. controls (92.30,284.93) and (100.00,300.14) .. (105.13,307.84)
  .. controls (110.27,315.55) and (130.02,339.05) .. (130.02,339.05)
  .. controls (130.02,339.05) and (110.80,312.47) .. (102.76,298.96)
  .. controls (94.67,285.33) and (90.12,273.48) .. (85.78,263.60)
  .. controls (82.65,256.50) and (79.22,240.88) .. (76.50,227.66)
  .. controls (73.73,214.23) and (72.94,200.60) .. (72.15,182.03)
  .. controls (71.36,163.47) and (70.97,161.30) .. (70.97,161.30);


\path [fill=black]  
  (64.65,226.08)
  -- (64.65,221.14) -- (80.25,220.15)
  -- (80.05,224.50) -- cycle
  %
  (71.36,250.37)
  -- (85.38,247.01) -- (84.59,243.06)
  -- (70.57,246.82) -- cycle
  %
  (82.42,279.01)
  -- (94.27,273.08) -- (93.09,269.33)
  -- (81.24,274.66) -- cycle
  %
 (96.84,305.87)
  -- (107.90,300.73) -- (106.52,297.18)
  -- (95.06,303.89)  -- cycle;


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: *Oh, barnacles!*

Comment: Amazing both: TikZ...and your skills :)

Comment: @MattAllegro I should stress is this not the result of artistry but the result of a svg stolen from the spongebob wiki and processed with regular expressions.